MongoDB: or in full text condition
I have data
[
  {
    "title": "Football Juventus"
  },
  {
    "title": "Football Milan"
  }
]

And index:
db['news'].createIndex({"title": "text"});

I want to select docs where Football + (Juventus | Milan)
But such query not works:
{
    $text: {
        $search: '"Football" ("Juventus" | "Milan")'
    }
}

Are any ideas?

Why not simply set up an index as "title": 1 and do a $in search like this?

Kindly check if regular expression search works for you.
A sample query may look like
db['news'].find( { title: { $regex: /^(Football\sJuventus)|(Football\sMilan)/ } } )

PS:

Above query is not tested.
Indexes work on case sensitive query
Reference document specified as https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/

